# Baby steps compile scss to css

Tags: css, wordpress, sass

I'm working on a WordPress website for work using a bought theme. I need to change the css of the header file, but the file is in scss. I need to compile it into css.

Can someone help me understand **how to compile the scss file into css in baby steps?**

I did read some tutorials, but they all required some knowledge in programming which I don't have. I think my question can be useful to other junior graphic designers who buy themes online. At some point we are confronted by the reality of not being a programmer.

The guys who made the theme suggested me Grunt. 
I have CodeKit in my disposition if it can be useful. I tried CodeKit but this error message appeared:

```
Libsass: Error: no mixin named scale
        on line 34 of Users/mtrahan/Downloads/werkstatt/assets/sass/_header.scss
>>      @include scale(1, 0);
```

-----------^

Comment: You could try something like the Scout-App. Although you seem to have gotten it working with what you have and it seems to be giving you a coding error. Maybe you dont have the proper scss files? Or not all the files?

Comment: Based on the error message, it looks like there's a problem with the code itself. Somewhere among your theme's SCSS files, do you see some code like `@mixin scale`? If not, that's why Libsass (the Sass compiler) says it's missing.

Comment: Actually, re-reading this I see the file in question is named "_header.scss". Are you trying to compile this file only? Most often these prefixed files are imported in another main file. That's the one you should be compiling.

Comment: If who did the theme suggested you to use Grunt, maybe there ir a configuration file called `Gruntfile.js` so you could use Grunt. You could check the theme folder for that file and a `package.json`. If you have those two files you are just steps away to compile the `scss` files. Otherwise you could install `node-sass` or the Ruby gem, based on the OS you are using.

Comment: I found a Gruntfile.js and a package.json file in the theme folder. I also found a package-lock.json file. I'm trying to install grunt. I have sucessfully managed to install npm and  Node.js. But I'm stuck at the next step.

Comment: Now run `npm install` in the project folder where the `package.json` is stored

Comment: Do you installed `grunt-cli`? You will also need it: `npm install grunt-cli -g`

Comment: The website for `werkstatt` theme says it is sold with the compiled CSS files. Is there a reason why you need to recompile the SASS source? (maybe to change some variables)

Comment: You can try `npm install && npm build`

Comment: @cgTag that will not work (`npm build` if the `package.json` does not have a `build` script defined. Better just run `grunt` after the installation.

Comment: @muecas true. but having a "build" command is an unspoken standard. This is an example of why there should be one. So that anyone can build it just by running install and build. They shouldn't need to know what it uses grunt.

Comment: @cgTag yes, i agree, this should be done with a postinstall script, so everything will be build automatically, just by running `npm install`. Bad practices everywhere my friend! :)

Comment: Done with "npm install in the project folder where the package.json is stored". Now, what dependencies I need? And how to install them? Between, the creators of the theme told me I could write "grunt release" and it will automatically compile the files. Thank you so much for the help so far!

Comment: @cgTag My goal is to change the colors of the logo and menu in the header for specific row in WordPress. They told me that I need some custom CSS. Since I only know the basic of HTML and CSS I asked if I could copy/paste and modify the actual CSS. And then they started talking about the _header.scss.

Comment: You can see my "progress" here: https://imgur.com/a/cyikVCH